# Trouble setting up menu program

Tags: java, menu

I have this project to do in which I have to set up a menu driven program (java in eclipse).  It does not have to be a GUI, it can been done with a series of system.out.println's but this is where I am having problems.  I have most of the code done except for the setup portion.  Every part has to have a quit option and the program itself has 3 parts.  The first being to take in 3 numbers from 1 to 100 from the user, second to put them in ascending order, and 3rd to see if the numbers could form the sides of a triangle.  I have the code for step 2 and 3 done, but cannot get the opening menu portion to work.  it needs to be something so that when the user types in 1, it does option 1, 2 for 2, and 3 for 3, but option 2 and 3 can't work unless option 1 is already completed.  This is what I have so far, how can I get the rest to work?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Projcet  {


    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int A;
        int B;
        int C;
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int opt2;
        int opt3;
        int Exit;

        System.out.println("This program is used to determine if three integers between 1-100 can form the sides of a triangle");

        System.out.println("Enter your first number between 1 and 100");
        num1= console.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your second number between 1 and 100");
        num2 = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your third number between 1 and 100");
        num3 = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Select your next step");
        System.out.println("Do not select step 3 if step 2 is not completed");
        System.out.println("Exit");
        System.out.println("opt2-Order your number in ascending order");
        System.out.println("opt3-Determine if the three inputs form a triangle");
        opt3 = console.nextInt();
        opt2 = console.nextInt();
        Exit =
        opt2 = 




    public static void int(opt2)
            {   
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.util.*;
    public class projecttest
    {   public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int num, i, j, temp;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter the number of integers to sort:");
            num = input.nextInt();

            int array[] = new int[num];

            System.out.println("Enter " + num + " integers: ");

            for (i = 0; i < num; i++) 
              array[i] = input.nextInt();

            for (i = 0; i < ( num - 1 ); i++) {
              for (j = 0; j < num - i - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] > array[j+1]) 
                {
                   temp = array[j];
                   array[j] = array[j+1];
                   array[j+1] = temp;
                }
              }
            }

            System.out.println("Sorted list of integers:");

            for (i = 0; i < num; i++) 
                System.out.println(array[i]);



    public staic void int(opt3)
    {
    import java.util.*;
    public class triangle {

         static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          int a;
          int b;
          int c;

          System.out.println("Enter a number for a");
          System.out.println("Enter a number for b");
          System.out.println("Enter a number for c");

            a = console.nextInt();
            b = console.nextInt();
            c = console.nextInt();

                if (a+b>c && a+c>b && b+c>a)
                    {   
                        System.out.print("TRIANGLE");
                    }
                else
                    {   
                        System.out.print("NO TRIANGLE");
                    }

            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Part 2 & 3 doesn't make sense when working with Part 1. But since you only ask for Part 1, I would assume you would work on their integration after resolving Part 1.

```
boolean opt1Done = false;
System.out.println("Select your next step");
System.out.println("1: Exit");
System.out.println("2: Order your number in ascending order");
System.out.println("3: Determine if the three inputs form a triangle");
int answer = console.nextInt();
if (answer == 1) {
    //do whatever for option 1
    opt1Done = true;
} else if (answer == 2) {
    if (opt1Done) {
        //...... do whatever to order the numbers
    } else {
        System.out.println("you must complete Step 1 before Step 2");
    }
} else if (answer == 3) {
    if (opt1Done) {
        //... do whatever to determine if triangle or not
    } else {
        System.out.println("you must complete Step 1 before Step 3");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.